# Server Request Interrupted (H18) on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, multipartform-data

The Heroku support isn't very helpful (except the tips like "adding more logs would help") so let me try here.

We are encountering a lot of `503` recently. It's super easy to reproduce the `503` using `curl`:

```
curl —limit-rate=100 -s -X POST https://our.server.com/some/endpoint?[1-100] \
   --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------BOUNDARY' \
   --data-binary @test.txt
```

If the **test.txt** is large enough (e.g. 1Kb), the Heroku will trigger `503` soon (btw. it doesn't even need to be a multipart form data). So I assume there is some kind of DDoS protection as this happens even on our dead-simple Node.js + Express app along with the Node apps of my colleagues.

**If that's the case - is there any way to silent the `503` errors?**

These started to annoy us lately, as one of our endpoints expect the multipart-data now (but I'll repeat - this doesn't have to be a multipart-data it is also reproducible with application/json). If authentication fails - we send the `401`. Seems that is not enough to close the multipart stream?

What I understand is that Heroku buffers the multipart stream, leading to some kind of buffer overflow and in result -> triggering the `503`.

Code:

```
(...)
const router = require('express').Router()
// We are getting `401` for the first 10-100 requests, then -> 503 hopes in
router.post('/some/endpoint', async function (req, res, next) {
   return res.status(401).send('Test')
})
app.use('/', router)
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

It came out that the reason for the failure was a very old [Node.js bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12339) (I got the link from Taylor from Heroku support). Apparently, the is no fix for that yet except to fully handle the incoming stream.