# Nodejs:Error while sending response before consuming all request data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, multer

I am using multer to store files.To do this,i have a POST route with an authentication middleware.
The request it recieves is a multipart/form-data(a file and other text fields).

```
let upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter: validateRequest }).single("file");

//The validateRequest function in fileFilter validates the request.

router.post("/", auth,(req, res) => {
upload(req, res, async err => {
    //code for uploading follows
}
```

And here is the auth middleware

```
function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  if (!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied. No token provided");

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("privateKey"));
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid token");
  }
};
```

Now the problem is, calling this route with out the valid token header(x-auth-token) results in an **H18 "Server request interrupted"** error response on Heroku(Works fine on local machine!).

On the other hand, if i remove the file from the multipart/form-data request, all works well.

This error is generated because(in my opinion), the request is too large and a response is being sent before consuming all of the request.

So for now,as a temporary workaround, i removed the auth middleware & i put the authentication code inside the fileFilter(validateRequest) function so that all the incoming stream  will be fully handled before any response is sent.

Error gone,but now the validateRequest function *smells*.

Is there a way to use the auth middleware like before and do all the authentication related things only there?

[Here is a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56498812/server-request-interrupted-h18-on-heroku) describing the problem as an old nodejs bug with no fix.

Comment: Can you add all the code for your post route?

Comment: According to the documentation, the upload act as a middleware, can you try router.post(‘...’, auth, upload, (req, res, next) => {...} if you want to catch the error as you’ve done you must probably await for upload since the error handling is asynchrone other wise the request will be ended sonner that expexted

Comment: I have the same issues